# ReactNative: Image src not display properly

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm using ReactNative + Expo
As what i know ios now required the transport is using HTTPS, when using HTTP it doesn't render the image.

HTTPS: tested is working render properly
HTTP: test is not working

from google, it required this code into the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My question is I do not have /ios project this is pure reactnative, how to make it work in expo? if not able where should i put this info.plist?

I have try put under /src/ios/{projectname}/Info.plist is not working.

Comment: Without having Xcode project means /iOS folder in your react native project how would you like to upload the app into app store? Without that you can't enable iOS specific services like Push Notifications, Background modes, etc. You can't even make the .IPA file of the app and unable to show anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/406#issuecomment-317612578), it says that expo disables the ATS. And for the Info.plist you can modified in two ways. First one is with app.json check this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration), but it is little bit restricted. The second way is to eject project from expo and to modify everything that you want.

I think this should be the answer of your question.